# How to get full page screenshot including all the content of scrollable popup using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ashot

I am having one webpage which is having a scrollable popup, i want to achieve that on submitting the popup when an error occurs i can take full page screenshot including the entire content in popup.
I tried using Ashot fullpage screenshot but the issue is that only visible portion of popup is there in capture, i want entire popup content also as "Full Page Screen Capture " extension of the pop up provides.
Is there a way i can achieve this?
I am using selenium 3 and Java 8.
Browser is Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/how-to-take-full-document-screenshot-including-non-visible-parts

This link will help you to resolve this issue
You cant take fully screenshot in selenium ,you need to implement it by your self.